# Is Drive Knight a cyborg or a robot?

Tags: one-punch-man

In One Punch Man there are cyborgs and robots. For example G4 was a robot and Genos is a cyborg. But how about Drive Knight? He has something that would seem to be hair, though it could be artificial. And in the manga in a chapter,

> He mentions he can't fight anymore because he doesnt have more energy, which makes him look more like a robot than a cyborg, since the human part of cyborg is unlikely to be completely depleted of energy (this doesnt happen to humans either, you might be exhausted but it's difficult you are completely unable to move or through some punches)

So then, Is Drive Knight a cyborg or a robot?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Wikia page on Drive Knight:

> It is unknown if he is a remodeling cyborg or a robot.

I don't think that ONE really cares enough to designate him as a cyborg or a robot.

Comment: Also, those two options are the only single possibilities given how One Punch characters have random abilities and ones are the creation of the authors. He could very well be an old refrigerator that gained powers :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the wiki List of One-Punch Man characters.

> Drive Knight (駆動騎士, Kudō Kishi), at rank 9, is a black-uniformed cyborg with a white mask face and a single eye.

[image]

You can see more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One-Punch_Man_characters#Drive_Knight)